# Quoting command substituted value

Tags: fish

In bash you would do

```
touch "foo bar"
rm "$(echo foo bar)"
```

How would you do that in fish?

This doesn't work for obvious reasons:

```
touch "foo bar"
rm "(echo foo bar)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that without the quotes produces the desired output:

```
touch "foo bar"
rm (echo foo bar)
```

A test:

```
echo "foo bar" > foo
touch "foo bar"
rm (cat foo)
```

Comment: How would you then do the reverse? `touch foo bar; rm (echo foo bar)`